# What is the better way to spread my locationUpdate through all application?

Tags: android

I want to **broadcast** my locationUpdate from GoogleApi (which is inside Service) to 3 different activities. 
I can implement a simple callback, but this way I can send my location only to one place.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
    }
```

On another hand I can create BroadCastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            notifyListDataChanged();

        }
    };
```

but it looks ugly and takes a lot of time to code and maintain. Is there any other **simple** way to broadcast location updates from Service

Comment: Personally haven't used it, but maybe you could try [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

Comment: you can have list of callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several message bus implementations for Android, including Otto, EventBus, and others. Any one of them should work for this.

Comment: I had in mind the use of RxJava to implement a message bus (if one is already using Rx), but a random google search should turn up about a dozen libraries. That's not the point, though. The use of a message bus is the point. Selection of particular libraries is generally considered to be off-topic here.